Mass conservation in chemical equilibria
Please help me understand this, it's really confusing me!
So suppose we have an equilibrium $\ce{A <=> B}$, and that we have initial masses $m_{\text{A}}$ and $m_{\text{B}}$ of the substances. Say the masses are such that the reaction proceeds to the left, so that at equilibrium, $\ce A$ has gained some amount and $\ce B$ has lost some amount. Setting up an ICE box in the standard way, one can find the substance change, call it $x$, and we get new masses $m_{\text{A}} + x M_{\text{A}}$ and $m_{\text{B}} - x M_{\text{B}}$, where $M_{\text{A}}$ and $M_{\text{B}}$ are the molar masses of $\ce A$ and $\ce B$, respectively. Now, the new total mass is
$$
m_{\text{A}} + m_{\text{B}} + x(M_{\text{A}} - M_{\text{B}}),
$$
which (assuming $x > 0$), is only equal to the old total mass $m_{\text{A}} + m_{\text{B}}$ if $M_{\text{A}} = M_{\text{B}}$. This is obviously not true in general, so what's going on here? Shouldn't the total mass be conserved?

If there is reaction A <=> B, then molar masses of A and B must be identical and their subtraction zero, so the total mass is m_A + m_B.

Oh my god you're right. The problem I was working on involved six different compounds with long molecular formulas, and I had overlooked an element symbol inside one of the formulas when calculating molar masses. You made me realize that if we have something like $\ce{A + B + C <=> D + E + F}$, we must clearly have $M_{\ce A} + M_{\ce B} + M_{\ce C} - M_{\ce D} - M_{\ce E} - M_{\ce F} = 0 \ \text{g}/\text{mol}$ in order for the equation to even make sense. Thanks a lot!

In general, the total amount after reaction finalizes is given by:
$$n=n_0+\upsilon x$$
In terms of mass, this becomes:
$$\frac{m}{M}=\frac{m_0}{M_0}+\upsilon x$$
Which is equivalent to:
$$m=\frac{M}{M_0}m_0+M\upsilon x$$
Where:
$n$ = total final amount
$n_0$ = total initial amount
$m$ = total final mass
$m_0$ = total initial mass
$M$ = final molar mass of mixture
$M_0$ = final molar mass of mixture
$\upsilon$ = sum of the stoichiometric numbers of $\mathrm{A}$ and $\mathrm{B}$
The sum of stoichiometric numbers in this particular case is:
$$\upsilon=\upsilon_\mathrm{A}+\upsilon_\mathrm{B}=1-1=0$$
Subsituting above:
$$m=\frac{M}{M_0}m_0$$
The only way mass is conserved is if:
$$M=M_0\implies m=m_0$$
Which also means, in terms of individual molar masses and mole fractions:
$$X_\mathrm{A}M_\mathrm{A}+X_\mathrm{B}M_\mathrm{B}=X_{\mathrm{A}o}M_\mathrm{A}+X_{\mathrm{B}o}M_\mathrm{B}$$
$$X_\mathrm{A}M_\mathrm{A}+\left(1-X_\mathrm{A}\right)M_\mathrm{B}=X_{\mathrm{A}o}M_\mathrm{A}+\left(1-X_{\mathrm{A}o}\right)M_\mathrm{B}$$
Expanding and grouping like terms, we get:
$$\left(X_\mathrm{A}-X_{\mathrm{A}o}\right)\left(M_\mathrm{A}-M_\mathrm{B}\right)=0$$
This equation is satisfied if one of two things happen:
(1) $X_\mathrm{A}=X_{\mathrm{A}_O}$
(2) $M_\mathrm{A}=M_\mathrm{B}$
The first (1) is physically impossible since some $\mathrm{A}$ is formed during the reaction, thus: $X_\mathrm{A}>X_{\mathrm{A}o}$
The second (2) is physically possible (for example, isomers) and the only way mass is conserved:
$$M_\mathrm{A}=M_\mathrm{B}\implies M=M_0\implies m=m_0$$

Strictly mass is never conserved; mass-energy is conserved; who knows what might happen under closer inspection. The conservation od mass is based on atoms not changing their mass in chemical reactions but perhaps electrons do?

@jimchmst That is perhaps true; however, such considerations are way beyond the intended scope of a high school level problem such as this one.

@jimchmst  With M=100 g/mol and reaction enthalpy 50 kJ/mol, the relative mass change is about 5 . 10^-12. That is far below uncertainties  of molar masses of elements and compounds, especially ones with variability of isotope composition.

In SR context, mass is not exactly additive property. The mass of an atom is not the exact sum of masses of the nucleus and the electrons.
